# Day N retention in BigQuery, error message: Invalid time zone

Tags: sql, datetime, timezone, google-bigquery

I'm trying to calculate Day N retention on a dataset in google Big Query. The table consists of one month of data from a mobile app and I want to find out how many users returned each day. I am using standardSQL. So far the code I have is

```
SELECT date(d1.eventDate) as dt,
        COUNT(distinct d1.userID) as total_users,
        COUNT(distinct d2.userID) as retained_users
         FROM `dataset` as d1
        LEFT JOIN `dataset` as d2 ON 
        d1.userID = d2.userID
        AND date(d1.eventDate) = date(datetime(d2.eventDate, '-1 day'))
          GROUP BY 1
          ORDER BY 1"
```

When I try to execute I get the error message

```
  Error: Invalid time zone: -1 day [invalidQuery]
```

My table structure is

```
    eventDate           | UserID | 
2016-05-06 00:00:00 UTC | 100000 |
2016-05-06 00:00:00 UTC | 200000 |
2016-05-06 00:00:00 UTC | 300000 |
```

What should I be using instead of '-1 day'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIMESTAMP_SUB` would fix the query as written, but might not be good enough as a solution for performance reasons. But at least it gets you the 1 day substraction:

```
SELECT date(d1.created_at) as dt,
        COUNT(distinct d1.actor.id) as total_users,
        COUNT(distinct d2.actor.id) as retained_users
         FROM `githubarchive.month.201810` as d1
        LEFT JOIN `githubarchive.month.201810` as d2 ON 
        d1.actor.id = d2.actor.id
        AND date(d1.created_at) = date(TIMESTAMP_SUB(d2.created_at, INTERVAL -24 HOUR))
          GROUP BY 1
          ORDER BY 1
```

To improve performance, do some de-duping before the JOIN:

```
SELECT day as dt,
    COUNT(distinct d1.id) as total_users,
    COUNT(distinct d2.id) as retained_users
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT actor.id, DATE(created_at) day FROM `githubarchive.month.201810`)as d1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT actor.id,  DATE(TIMESTAMP_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL -24 HOUR)) day FROM `githubarchive.month.201810`) as d2 
USING (id, day)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and is further optimized to not to use any JOINs but rather using analytic functions

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  day, 
  COUNT(1) total_users,
  COUNTIF(delta = 1) retained_users
FROM (
  SELECT
    day, id, 
    DATE_DIFF(day, LAG(day) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY day), DAY) delta
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      DATE(created_at) day,
      actor.id
    FROM `githubarchive.month.201810`
  )
)
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```

or, if to use original question's notation:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  day, 
  COUNT(1) total_users,
  COUNTIF(delta = 1) retained_users
FROM (
  SELECT
    day, userID, 
    DATE_DIFF(day, LAG(day) OVER(PARTITION BY userID ORDER BY day), DAY) delta
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      DATE(eventDate) day,
      userID
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY day
```